# How not to show some fields in digital certificate details after it has been created?

Tags: digital-certificate

I am new in digital certificate field and I recently have countered a question. Actually, I want to use subscriber's phone number as a part of subject name when the certificate is created but for privacy reason I don't want the phone number to be shown in certificate details after it is created. Is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: I know how to include the phone number in the certificate, and I know the OID,too. But I don't know if it is possible to hide the phone number in certificate details. If it is possible, I don't have any idea how.